# ライトマップをベイクしたプレハブをResources.Loadで読み込んだ場合

Tags: unity3d

背景モデルにライト情報をbakeの設定で焼き付け、プレハブ化したものを別シーンで使用したいと思っています。
あらかじめヒエラルキーにプレハブを放り込んだ場合はただしくライトマップが反映されているのですが、シーンの途中でプログラムからResources.Loadで読み込み実体化した場合、bakeではなく全てリアルタイムの処理がなされており、焼き付けの影よりも精度が落ちています。
上記のような工程でも正しく焼き付けのライトマップを使える方法があるでしょうか。
あるいはunityの仕様なのでしょうか？　（ちなみに5.1.1のパーソナル版を使用しています）